# C++ VirtualQueryEx infinite loop

Tags: c++, memory

I'm currently re-creating a memory modifier application using C++, the original was in C#.

All credit goes to "gimmeamilk" who's tutorials Ive been following on [YouTube(video 1 of 8)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRPMdb1YMS8&feature=share&list=UUnxW29RC80oLvwTMGNI0dAg). I would highly recommend these tutorials for anyone attempting to create a similar application.

The problem I have is that my VirtualQueryEx seems to run forever. The process I'm scanning is "notepad.exe" and I am passing to the application via command line parameter.

```
std::cout<<"Create scan started\n";
#define WRITABLE (PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE | PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY) //These are all the flags that will be used to determin if a memory block is writable.
MEMBLOCK * mb_list = NULL;          //pointer to the head of the link list to be returned
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;   //holder for the VirtualQueryEx return struct
unsigned char *addr = 0;            //holds the value to pass to VirtualQueryEx

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false, pid);
if(hProc) 
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(VirtualQueryEx(hProc,addr, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo)) == 0) 
        {
            break;
        }


        if((meminfo.State & MEM_COMMIT) && (meminfo.Protect & WRITABLE)) //((binary comparison of meminfos state and MEM_COMMIT, this is basically filtering out memory that the process has reserved but not used)())
        {
            MEMBLOCK * mb = create_memblock(hProc, &meminfo);
            if(mb)
            {
                mb->next = mb_list;
                mb_list = mb;
            }
        }
        addr = (unsigned char *)meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize;//move the adress along by adding on the length of the current block

    }
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"Failed to open process\n";
}
std::cout<<"Create scan finished\n";

return mb_list;
```

The output from this code results in

```
Create scan started on process:7228
```

Then it does not return anything else to the console. Unfortunately the example source code linked to via the Youtube video is no longer available.
(7228 will change based on the current pid of notepad.exe)

**edit-reply to question @Hans Passant**
I still don't understand, what I think Im doing is

```
Starting a infinite loop
{
   Testing using vqx if the address is valid and populating my MEM_BASIC_etc..
   {
        (has the process commited to using that addr of memory)(is the memory writeable)
        {
            create memblock etc
        } 
   }
   move the address along by the size of the current block
}
```

My program is x32 and so is notepad (as far as I'm aware).

Is my problem that because I'm using a x64 bit OS that I'm actually inspecting half of a block (a block here meaning the unit assigned by the OS in memory) and its causing it to loop?

Big thanks for your help! I want to understand my problem as well as fix it.

Comment: My crystal ball says you are running this code on a 64-bit operating system.  You'll need to break out of the loop if the AllocationBase truncates to 0 because it can't map the address space of a 64-bit process in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Your crystal ball is correct! Ill give it a try and get back :D thanks!!

Comment: @HansPassant Please see my reply under "edit-reply to question Hans Passant", Thanks!

Comment: No, notepad is a 64-bit process.  This basically boils down to doing something that doesn't make sense, a 32-bit process cannot discover the virtual address space mapping of a 64-bit process.  You'll need to build a 64-bit version of your program.  Add the x64 platform target.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I was unwittingly trying to run before I could walk, my poor assumption that notepad was x32. I created a quick x32 bit application to test my code on and it worked flawlessly, I will however use your advice when I implement the x64 application scanner.

If you post answer I'll give you the appropriate rep!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're compiling a 32 bit program and using it to parse the memory of a 64 bit program.  You define 'addr' as a unsigned char pointer, which in this case is 32 bits in size.  It cannot contain a 64 bit address, which is the cause of your problem.

If your target process is 64 bit, compile your program as 64 bit as well.  For 32 bit target processes, compile for 32 bit.  This is typically the best technique for dealing with the memory of external processes and is the fastest solution.

Depending on what you're doing, you can also use #ifdef and other conditionals to use 64 bit variables depending on the target, but the original solution is usually easier.